# Экранирование спец. символов HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Как вывести HTML-код без интерпретации последнего браузером как инструкции?
Код:

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.vk.com/method/users.get",
    data: {
        user_ids: '1',
        v: "5.26"
    },
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (e) {alert(e.response[0].first_name + ' ' + e.response[0].last_name);}
});
</script>
```

То есть, у меня выводиться `alert`, имя-фамилия была в моем блоке `div` на самой странице.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: вместо алерт напишите например `document.getElementByID('ваш_див').innerHTML = e.response[0].first_name` и так далее.

Answer (score 2):

Превратить спец. символы в [символы-мнемоники HTML](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%B2_HTML):

```html
&#x3C;script&#x3E;
    $.ajax({
    url: &#x22;https://api.vk.com/method/users.get&#x22;,
    data: {
        user_ids: &#x27;1&#x27;,
        v: &#x22;5.26&#x22;
    },
    dataType: &#x22;jsonp&#x22;,
    success: function (e) {alert(e.response[0].first_name + &#x27; &#x27; + e.response[0].last_name);}
});
&#x3C;/script&#x3E;
```

**UPD**:

Если надо выполнить код и вывести браузер только ответ запроса, то так:

```js
// Если в ответе будут спец. символы, эта функция их превратит в мнемоники
function encodeHTML(raw){
  return raw.replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/gim, i => '&#' + i.charCodeAt(0) + ';');
}

$.ajax({
  url: "https://api.vk.com/method/users.get",
  data: {
    user_ids: '1',
    v: "5.26"
  },
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function(e) {
    // Ищем нужный div (тут это #response) и вставляем туда ответ, пропущенный через мясорубку спец. символов
    // (чтобы не нароком не выполнился)
    document.querySelector('#response').innerHTML = encodeHTML(e.response[0].first_name + ' ' + e.response[0].last_name);
    //alert(e.response[0].first_name + ' ' + e.response[0].last_name);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='response'>Answer</div>
```

Comment: Вы не так поняли, нужно чтоб скрипт работал, но результат чтоб выводился не в алерт окне, а в html

Comment: @DMEE, в вопросе вы указали именно вывод этого кода как текст, все согласились, правку приняли. Пишите задачу правильно.